# Finding reason why it generating error: for = 4 while using python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was given a exercise to assign value 4 to variable 'for' it generates error. I tried to find out the reason but I didnt got any

The error is as follows:

```
  Cell In[1], line 1
     for = 4
         ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried searching a lot why am I getting error

Comment: You can't use `for` as a variable name, it's a language keyword (used for looping).

Comment: `for` is a reserved word.

Comment: `for` is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), you can't use it as variable name

Comment: If the exercise specifically told you to use that variable name, I guess the point was for you to learn that certain names are reserved.

Answer (score 1):

`for` is a special keyword in Python, so it cannot be used as a variable.

For more information, and a list of other keywords, read the keyword section of the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).